# What is the difference in interfaces generated by different flatc compilers (Win64/ Win 32/ Mac)?

Tags: c++, macos, serialization, cmake, flatbuffers

For different architecture and environment (like Win64/ Win 32/ Mac) cmake generates different projects, which further compiles to give different flatc compilers. My doubt is:

1. Do these flatc compilers generate same interfaces (Cpp headers) from a given schema, or there is some difference in them?
2. Why is there so much difference in size of these flatc executable, in case they perform same functionality!
3. Should I use different flatc to generate schema on different platforms? or can use the same generated interfaces on all three platforms?

Please help.

stats for release flatc binaries from flatbuffers-1.8.0:

- win64     1238KB
- win32     961KB
- mac       1145KB

Github project: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers

Comment: What is the name of the different `flatc` compilers?  Are you using GNU, Visual Studio, IAR, Greenhills or some other vendor?

Comment: I made and compiled flatc compilers for "Visual Studio 14, Visual Studio 14 Win64, and Xcode" as mentioned on [link](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_building.html).

Comment: BTW, your terminology sounds like you created compilers or modified the compilers for `flatc`; or used a special compiler called "flatc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. This has to do with the C++ compilers, and has nothing to do with FlatBuffers. You'll get size differences for any C++ program you compile with multiple compilers / architectures. Those size differences you quote are actually fairly small (Xcode defaults to 64 bits btw).
3. It does not matter which flatc you use, output will be identical.